# How to run Fritzing on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, arduino

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and then installed [Fritzing](https://fritzing.org/) using packages from official repository by using below command

```
sudo apt-get install fritzing
```

Then on first launch it showed three windows with errors

> **Oops!**
> Sorry, we have a problem with the swapping mechanism.
> Fritzing still works, but you won't be able to change parts properties.
>
> **Fritzing**
> Cannot read file /home/username/bins/core.fzb:
> No such file or directory.
>
> **Fritzing**
> Fritzing cannot load the parts bin

and the parts list was empty as the result. I need to run Fritzing for my hobby project.

Comment: I dont know of an Ubuntu 18.04.7 LTS on 10/28/2021...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we have a problem here - the official [Fritzing 0.9.3b deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fritzing) which is broken in 18.04 LTS.
I have reported a [bug 1949087](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fritzing/+bug/1949087) about such behaviour.

Also I have created [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/fritzing) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Fritzing 0.9.3b from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
So one can install the deb-packaged version using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/fritzing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fritzing
```

and it will function normally on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
To have updated parts use the hack below:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/fritzing/parts

sudo apt-get install git
sudo git clone https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts.git -b develop /usr/share/fritzing/parts
```

---

It should be noted that packages even for Ubuntu 21.10 is [still 0.9.3b](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/fritzing), so same version.
So if one needs newer version, then there is a way to replace it with [Flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.fritzing.Fritzing) as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove fritzing

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak install flathub org.fritzing.Fritzing
```

and then enjoy Fritzing 0.9.6 as the result.

Comment: Wow. Flatpak on an Ubuntu installation. That seems almost sacrilegious 

Answer (score 0):

I got this error code on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS with Fritzing version 0.9.3 (downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Center):

> Unable to find parts git repository #3890

I managed to get the parts git repository work by:

```
sudo apt remove fritzing-parts
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then reinstalling:

```
sudo apt install fritzing-parts
```